# How to make a ListView stop adding and scrolling?

Tags: flutter

I have a list of user-favorited words I would like to be shown on the screen, and I used a ListView.builder to do this. It looks something like this:

```
ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder(context, i) {
        return ListTile(
            title: Text(words[i])
)})
```

The issue is, eventually I run out of words, and then I get an error. I would really like it if the ListView would simply be able to stop trying to add new widgets and not be able to scroll past what has been already generated. Is this possible, or should I look to a different type of display widget?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListView.builder` has a property `itemCount` where you can give the length of items the `List` will contain.

In your example:

```dart
ListView.builder(
    // Here specify the number of items
    itemCount: words.length,
    itemBuilder(context, i) {
        return ListTile(
            title: Text(words[i])
)})
```

Answer (score 0):

Limit the number of `ListView` with `itemCount`.

```
List<String> words = [
     'one',
     'two',
     'three',
     'four',
     'five',
     'six',
     'seven',
     'eight',
     'nine',
     'ten',
     '1',
     '2',
     '3',
     '4'
   ];

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: words.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(title: Text(words[index])),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```